# find youtube video by year

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am using below code to find Youtube videos based on entred keyword , however I also want to filter videos by their upload date

```
var q = "keyword";
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
   q: q,
   part: 'snippet'
});

request.execute(function(response) {
  var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
  $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
});
```

I couldn't find any place where I can pass year as a parameter in Data API page .Is it possible to filter videos by year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` like the following :

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    q: 'keyword',
    part: 'snippet',
    publishedAfter: '2016-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    publishedBefore: '2017-01-01T00:00:00Z'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help